# Write on publish the first time, but not overwrite after that

Tags: c#, visual-studio, publish

I have published an application via Visual Studio that uses a access database, the database is empty at first, and while running the published app I've added data to the database.

I would now like to update the application with changes I've made to the forms and added a new table and added columns to the original tables

However I want to keep the newly added data that is in the database and so far I cannot find a way of doing it, the forms either stay as they are or the database gets wiped

Anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: What kind of app is that?

Comment: How about first exporting all data from the "old" one to, say, a bunch of CSV or Excel files, then replacing the db, then importing the backup data into the new db? Or simpler still: copy the old db to a temp folder, deploy the new one, import data from old db. delete old db.

Comment: Interesting idea @LocEngineer 

On the new update I could create a button where it promps the user to input the location of the old database, it will then read in all the data from all tables and input it into the new database?

Comment: Why, doesn't your app _know_ where the db is? Yes, of course a prompt would work too but is it necessary?

Comment: @LocEngineer Yes the app knows where it is, however I've tried copying the old database and pasting it into the new database and that doesn't work. I've also tried copying the new files into the old files to try update the forms and that doesn't work either

Comment: Easy.  Publish the database to folder X.  Plan on accessing the database in folder Y.  Go look for Y.  If it doesn't exist, create and copy the database. If it does exist, look for the database in Y.  If it doesn't exist, copy it there. If it does exist, use that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little (untested!!) snippet. You will have to adjust some values but it should get you started. It works with Access interop, copies the db, deletes all tables from the newly deployed db, imports them from the old, then deletes the temp files.

```
var dbPath = "[path to your db]";

var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
var tempPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments), guid);
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(tempPath);
var tempDb = Path.Combine(tempPath, "[yourdbname]");
System.IO.File.Copy("[path to your db]", tempDb, true);

//copy the old database to this tempPath
//Overwrite the original old db with your new one
var access = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application();
access.OpenCurrentDatabase(filepath: "[path to your db]", Exclusive: true, bstrPassword: "");
var newdb = access.CurrentDb();
var tableList=new List<string>();
foreach (TableDef table in newdb.TableDefs)
{
    tableList.Add(table.Name);
    newdb.TableDefs.Delete(table.Name);
}
foreach (var table in tableList)
{
    access.DoCmd.TransferDatabase(AcDataTransferType.acImport, DatabaseTypeEnum.dbVersion140, tempDb,
        AcObjectType.acTable, table, table, false, false);
}
System.IO.Directory.Delete(tempPath, true);
```

Comment: hi @LocEngineer I'm currently trying to implement the code bit by bit, however after running the code once, if it fails it seem's the 'connection' to the database is staying opened even when the program has stopped running, I've tried the following lines on a catch statement `System.IO.Directory.Delete(tempPath, true);
        access.CloseCurrentDatabase();` but unsuccessful, it's stopping me retrying as I have to restart the computer each time, any suggestions?

Comment: put `access.CloseCurrentDatabase();` and aditionally `access.Quit();` in a `finally`block. This should ensure the connection if terminated and the process killed. You certainly don't have to restart the computer. In the worst case right now you should be fine killing any remaining process from TaskManager.